# How can i declare variables inside LINQ method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can i declare variables in below method

For example:

```
double price = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text);
```

```
double total = GvProducts.Rows
                         .Cast<GridViewRow>()
                         .Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked)
                         .Sum(r => 
                              double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text) * 
                              double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text));
```

Comment: With query syntax you can use the `let` keyword, in method syntax you could use an anonymous type.

Comment: `r => { double price = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text); /* do something with price */; return price; }`. Note that if you are passing an Expression (I believe in this case you are *not*), then you are unable to write an expression block (and thus cannot define a variable inside the expression)

Answer (score 1):

When any method expects a `Func` you have two possibilites (or to be exact three).

1. Add a single-line-expression (as already done)
2. Add the name of a delegate:

   `Sum(x => MyMethod(x))`
   Where `MyMethod` is a method within your class returning an `int` and expecting a `T`).
3. Add a multi-line expression embraced in curly brackets:

   `Sum(x => { /* any statements */ })`